# Unable to read beyond the end of the stream. Azure Deployment Issue

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, office365, office365-apps, office365api

I want to integrate office 365 API's and i'm following this sample git code [enter link description here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-ASPNETMVC-Start) i follow all the steps and everything is working fine in localhost but when i deploy the same asp application on git it gives me following error **Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.**It can be this git line issue `// place the entry in memory
            this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : Cache.cacheBits);`
I debug my app, when i debug this app by providing localDB connectionString  It works fine but when i change connectionString to online it throws above mention exception on the above mention line

Answer (score 0):

I have sold issue by replacing local DB connection String to Online GB Connection String and than run migration

The problem was with migrated data actually when we deploy on Azure htat's why we have to run online migration first than deploy